# Finding the current id of an object and appending it dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to add a *dynamic* object to another *dynamic* object. Below I have a short code on what I am trying to do. It is having trouble for some reason to find the **id** again.

First block that creates the second block:

```
var comp_idx = 0;
function addComponent() {
  var html = '<div id="comp_row' + comp_idx + '" class="row padding610">' +
    '<h5>Component</h5>' +
    '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col s4">' +
        '<div class="input-field">' +
                '<label for="comp_note' + comp_idx + '">Component Notes</label>' +
            '<input name="comp_note' + comp_idx + '" type="text" id="comp_note' + comp_idx + '" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col s4">' +
        '<div class="input-field">' +
          '<label for="comp_sku' + comp_idx + '">Component SKU/Description</label>' +
          '<input name="comp_sku' + comp_idx + '" type="text" id="comp_sku' + comp_idx + '" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col s4">' +
        '<div class="input-field">' +
          '<label for="comp_quantity' + comp_idx + '">Quantity</label>' +
          '<input name="comp_quantity' + comp_idx + '" type="text" id="comp_quantity' + comp_idx + '" />' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<h5>RMAT Material SKUs Needed</h5>' +
        '<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">' +
            '<input type="button" id="add-button-comp' + comp_idx + '" value="Add Additional Raw Materials" onclick="addRMATComp()" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div id="rmatsComp' + comp_idx + '" class="brown lighten-2"></div>' +
            '<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">' +
                '<input type="button" id="add-button-comp' + comp_idx + '" value="Add Non Machine Charges To Component" onclick="addNmcQuoteItemComp()" />' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div id="NonMachineQuoteComp' + comp_idx + '" class="brown lighten-4"></div>' +
          '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="col s12">' +
                '<div class="input-field"><a onclick="removeElement(\'comp_row' + comp_idx + '\');" id="delete-icon"' + 'class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-del-comp">Delete Component</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="row">' +
                        '<div class="divider-row"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
    '</div>';
  $('#ComponentDetails').append(html);
  comp_idx++;
  $('select').select2();
}
```

The second function that creates the other element:

```
var rmatComp_idx = 0;
function addRMATComp() {
  var html =
    '<div id="rmatComp_row' + rmatComp_idx + '" class="row padding2">' +
        '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="col s4">' +
                '<div class="input-field">' +
                    '<select id="comp_rmat_type' + rmatComp_idx + '" name="comp_rmat_type' + rmatComp_idx + '" class="browser-defaultR" onchange="loadRmatByType(\'comp_rmat_type' + rmatComp_idx + '\',\'comp_rmat_select' + rmatComp_idx + '\')">' + 
            '<?php echo str_replace('\'', '"', $rmatStockTypeOptions); ? > ' + 
                        '</select>'+
          '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="col s4">' +
          '<div class="input-field">' +
            '<select id="comp_rmat_select' + rmatComp_idx + '" name="comp_rmat_select' + rmatComp_idx + '" class="browser-defaultR" onchange="loadRmat(\'comp_rmat_type' + rmatComp_idx + '\',\'comp_rmat_select' + rmatComp_idx + '\',\'comp_rmat_desc' + rmatComp_idx + '\',\'comp_rmat_cost' + rmatComp_idx + '\',\'comp_rmat_markup' + rmatComp_idx + '\',\'comp_rmat_unit' + rmatComp_idx + '\')">' +
                    '</select>' + 
          '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col s4">' +
          '<div class="input-field">' +
            '<label for="comp_rmat_desc' + rmatComp_idx + '">Description</label>' +
            '<input name="comp_rmat_desc' + rmatComp_idx + '" type="text" id="comp_rmat_desc' + rmatComp_idx + '" />' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col s1">' +
        '<div class="input-field">' +
          '<label for="comp_rmat_qty' + rmatComp_idx + '">Quantity</label>' +
          '<input name="comp_rmat_qty' + rmatComp_idx + '" type="number" id="comp_rmat_qty' + rmatComp_idx + '" class="comp_rmat_qty" ' + 'onblur="calculateRMAT(' + rmatComp_idx + ')"/>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
    '<div class="col s1">' +
      '<div class="input-field">' +
        '<label for="comp_rmat_cost' + rmatComp_idx + '">Cost</label>' +
        '<input name="comp_rmat_cost' + rmatComp_idx + '" type="number" id="comp_rmat_cost' + rmatComp_idx + '" step="0.01" class="comp_rmat_cost"  ' + 'onblur="calculateRMAT(' + rmatComp_idx + ')"/>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col s2">' +
      '<div class="input-field">' +
        '<label for="comp_rmat_true_cost' + rmatComp_idx + '">Cost Without Markup</label>' +
        '<input name="comp_rmat_true_cost' + rmatComp_idx + '" type="number" id="comp_rmat_true_cost' + rmatComp_idx + '" step="0.01"  ' + 'onblur="calculateRMAT(' + rmatComp_idx + ')" readonly/>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col s1">' +
      '<div class="input-field">' +
        '<label for="comp_rmat_markup' + rmatComp_idx + '">Markup</label>' +
        '<input name="comp_rmat_markup' + rmatComp_idx + '" type="number" id="comp_rmat_markup' + rmatComp_idx + '" step="0.001" class="comp_rmat_markup"' + 'onblur="calculateRMAT(' + rmatComp_idx + ')"/>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col s2">' +
      '<div class="input-field">' +
        '<label for="comp_rmat_extended' + rmatComp_idx + '" class="active">Extended</label>' +
        '<input name="comp_rmat_extended' + rmatComp_idx + '" type="text" id="comp_rmat_extended' + rmatComp_idx + '" readonly/>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col s1">' +
      '<div class="input-field">' +
        '<label for="comp_rmat_unit' + rmatComp_idx + '">Unit of Measure</label>' +
        '<input name="comp_rmat_unit' + rmatComp_idx + '" type="text" id="comp_rmat_unit' + rmatComp_idx + '" readonly/>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col s4">' +
      '<div class="input-field">' +
        '<label for="comp_rmat_instructions' + rmatComp_idx + '">RMAT Instructions</label>' +
        '<input name="comp_rmat_instructions' + rmatComp_idx + '" type="text" id="comp_rmat_instructions' + rmatComp_idx + '" />' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col s12">' +
        '<div class="input-field">' +
          '<a onclick="removeElement(\'rmatComp_row' + rmatComp_idx + '\');" id="delete-icon" ' + 'class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat btn-del-row">Delete RMAT Row</a>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</div>';

  $('#rmatsComp' + rmatComp_idx + '').append(html);
  //console.log(html);
  rmatComp_idx++;

  $('select').select2();

  alert(comp_idx);
}
```

The `rmatsComp` is created dynamically on another function. Below is the button:

```
<input type="button" id="add-button-comp0" value="Add Additional Raw Materials" onclick="addRMATComp()">
```

If anyone can see the issue or point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

[Here is an example i wrote to make it smaller. Hopefully its clear what I want to do.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWBBXw)

Comment: You will have to post more code than this

Comment: Preferably a jsbin or fiddle

Comment: your code looks fine. need the rest of the code to figure out whats wrong. here check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eb5cnc6d/

Comment: Maybe you should empty the "$('#rmatsComp' + rmatComp_idx)" first, then append stuff.

Comment: It is hard to judge what's going on without full code example. Looks like some race conditioning or something. One thing, by replacement `onclick` to event listener you can keep element's references in the code, and thus get rid of necessity unique id marks. Although it is, again, hard to say without looking at full listing.